# What is the difference between == and === in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, equals-operator, identity-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)
>   [When would JavaScript == make more sense than ===?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132878/when-would-javascript-make-more-sense-than)

What is the difference between below methods in  comparing a string with undefined value.

```
 var x; 
 if(x==undefined) 
 { 
  alert(x); 
 }
```

and

```
if(x===undefined)
{ 
  alert(x); 
}
```

Why should i prefer second method in this case.. Please let me know advantages..

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132878/when-would-javascript-make-more-sense-than/2132895#2132895

Comment: @deceze Scenarios are different...

Comment: @user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776950/javascript-undefined-undefined then.

Comment: == doesn't check the datatype where as === do check the datatype

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- `==` attempts to convert the values to the same type before testing if they're the same. `"5" == 5`
- `===` does not do this; it requires objects to be of the same type to be equal. `"5" !== 5`

In this case, the result is:

- `x == undefined` will be true if `x` is `undefined` or `null`.
- `x === undefined` will only be true if `x` is `undefined`.

You should prefer the first method if you'd like undefined and null to be treated equivalently. One common use of this is optional function arguments.

```
function greet(name, greeting) {
    if (name == undefined) name = 'World';
    if (greeting == undefined) greeting = 'Hello';
    alert(greeting + ' ' + name);
}

greet(); // alerts "Hello World"
greet("Bob"); // alerts "Hello Bob"
greet(null, "Goodbye"); // alerts "Goodbye World"
```

Answer (score 9):

suppose we have  x=5,

== is equal to

x==8 is false
x==5 is true

=== is exactly equal to (value and type)

x===5 is true
x==="5" is false

Hope you understand this concept

Answer (score 8):

`===` checks for the same type as well. You'll understand with a few examples:

```
(1 == '1') //Returns true
```

Since `==` doesn't bother with types, that returns true. However, if you want strict type checking, you'd use `===` because that returns true *only* if the it's of the same type, and is the same value.

```
(1 === '1') //Returns false
(1 === 1) //Returns true
```

> - Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of    characters, same length, and same characters in corresponding
>     positions.
> - Two numbers are strictly equal when they are numerically    equal (have the same number value). NaN is not equal to anything,
>     including NaN. Positive and negative zeros are equal to one another.
> - Two Boolean operands are strictly equal if both are true or both are    false.
> - Two objects are strictly equal if they refer to the same    Object.
> - Null and Undefined types are == (but not ===).

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Answer (score 7):

== is just comparing the two values, and if they are of different types, type conversion is done

=== compares the values and well as their types - so no type conversion will be done here.